# How to see in MSDN only the properties/methods added by a .NET class, and not those inherited?

Tags: .net, documentation, msdn

For example, the `ContextMenu` WPF class [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.aspx) (either offline or online) has pages and pages of properties and methods. Can I filter them somehow and only see the ones added by `ContextMenu`, like `StaysOpen`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the tree structure on the left of that page, click on  [*ContextMenu Properties*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu_properties.aspx) , you then get another page full of properties, but if you look to the left again you see just the properties belonging to the ContextMenu class.